# Variability in 4.5 billion year age of earth based on radioactive dating of meteorites?

Tags: earth-history, dating, radioactivity

Which meteorites in particular give an age of 4.5 billion years and which isotopes are used for radioactive analysis? Is there much variability if different meteorites or isotopes are used?